# How to create view page Flutter but without go page like instagram press long picture?

Tags: flutter, dart, view, instagram, navigator

I want to make a widget image if long press it will appear like a page, but if I release it doesn't see like a page anymore,

How to do this in Flutter?

Like a popup menu but if you release it it won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

add InkWell before the image and add in InkWell on long press
then add state less widget preview the image as popup Like this:

```
InkWell(
 onLongPress:(){
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder(context)=>ImageView(img:"url of image"));
} ,
child:Image.network("url of image")

),
```

and add state less widget to display the image:

```
class ImageView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageView( {Key? key, required this.img}) : super(key: key);
final String img;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(

          child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50),
                  child: Image.network(img),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```